# How can I build a specific file with makefile?

Tags: makefile

I want to compile a simple example C program (one of many). But I don't want to write out the whole command every time I build it (or spam the up arrow). Unfortunately I am not really good with makefile and I can't find anything.

I want this:

```bash
make example.c
```

to run this:

```
$(CC) $(C_FLAGS) example.c -o example
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the rule:

```
example: example.c
    $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) example.c -o example
```

and you type `make example`, it would invoke the recipe listed.   Note that the command line takes `example` (what you want to build) as opposed to `example.c` (which is what you want to build it from...)

If on the other hand you want a more generic rule, say, if you typed `make xxx`, and want it to compile `xxx.c` to `xxx` (where `xxx` can be any string) you could use a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html) as such:

```
% : %.c
   $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) $< -o $@
```

You can further restrict the patterns to only match a specific set of targets using a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage) as so:

```
TARGS := foo bar example

$(TARGS) : % : %.c
    $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) $< -o $@
```

which is cleaner, but requires you to maintain a list of possible targets.